# jQuery Validation Depending onselect option makes other fields required or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I have a form that when you click the checkbox it pops up another form. I am struggling making certain fields required using jQuery Validation. Basically what I am trying to accomplish is when the checkbox is clicked I want `AndOr1` to be required otherwise if the checkbox is not checked it will not be required.

But then to take it a step further depending on the option chosen for the select `AndOr1` I want it to control what is required and what is not. So if And is chosen I want name, address1, city, state and Zip REQUIRED and if Or is chosen I do not want any of the fields to be required.

Can someone please assist me in how I can do this please?

http://jsfiddle.net/Alexandra123/epjqz4nk/2/

```
function valueChanged1()
{
    if($('#anotherSeller1').is(":checked"))   
        $("#Form2").show();

    else
        $("#Form2").hide();
        $("#Form2 > .clearfix input:text").val("");
        $("#Form2 > select").val("");
        $("#anotherSeller2").prop("checked", false);


}
```

**Edit:** This question is different from [jquery - form validate rules required depends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905676/jquery-form-validate-rules-required-depends) because it takes it another step further. What this form is doing is only making `AndOr1` required depending if the checkbox is checked. (This is the same as the other question) But then what this one is supposed to be doing is depending on the select option chosen for `AndOr1` if And is chosen I want it to make `sellerName2` required and if Or is chosen I want it to make `sellerName2` not required. So this takes it the next step further.

The problem I am having is I can make it required depending on And or Or but if you hit submit when `AndOr1` has not been chosen yet I do not want it to make `sellerName2` required already. Only once And is chosen.

```
    <script>
             $("#form").validate({
    rules: {
        sellerName1: {
            required: true
        },
        AndOr1: {
            required: '#anotherSeller1:checked'
        },
        sellerName2: {
            required: '#anotherSeller1:checked > #AndOr1:Add'


        },
        // Same for other fields
    },
    messages: {
        sellerName1: "This field is required.",
        // Repeat for other fields
    }
});
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fix it:

```
$("#form").validate({
    rules: {
        sellerName1: {
            required: true
        },
        AndOr1: {
            required: '#anotherSeller1:checked'
        },
        sellerName2: {
            required: function(element) {
                return $("#AndOr1").val() == "And";

            }
        },
        // Same for other fields
    },
    messages: {
        sellerName1: "This field is required.",
        // Repeat for other fields
    }
});
```